# When did the defeated General José de la Cruz sail back to Spain?

Tags: military, 19th-century, spanish-empire, mexico, independence

[José de la Cruz](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_de_la_Cruz) was a Spanish military commander in Mexico's wars of independence. He was finally defeated by his ex-subordinate, Pedro Celestino Negrete in Durango, just after the Treaty of Córdoba, at the end of August or beginning of September of 1821.

The book ["101 villanos en la historia de México"](http://www.wikimexico.com/articulo/crueldad-realista-la-muerte-delos-insurgentes-jose-de-la-cruz) mentions that Agustín Iturbide let de la Cruz return to Spain. That would place the date of the permission before Iturbide's abdication in March of 1823. According to [Zelia Nuttall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zelia_Nuttall), in ["Two Remarkable California Baskets"](https://books.google.com/books?id=LIoRAAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA342&ots=AANBNPr-eg&dq=1821%20general%20jose%20de%20la%20cruz&pg=PA341#v=onepage&q&f=false), the general stopped in California first, which I find dubious. According to the Spanish Wikipedia article, in 1823 de la Cruz became Spain's Minister of War.

That leaves a range of up to about 18 months when de la Cruz could have crossed the Atlantic. More specifically, **when was his voyage to Spain**?